# Issue with setting up email sender with Django 1.8 and Plesk

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, plesk

I'm trying to configure a website using Django 1.8 and Plesk, and setting the email variables to any value gets the traceback below. I've tried with Gmail and the email server from the host, and the error is the same. I have tested Python's smtplib and successfully sent an email through that, so it looks like it may be something between Django and Plesk. If I set up the website on a test CentOS 6 server, then I don't run into this problem.

**Example Config settings**

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mypassword"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "user@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

**Traceback**

```
mod_wsgi (pid=1703): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/s1085163.instanturl.net/oozoa.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in __call__
return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 256, in handle_uncaught_exception
'request': request
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in error
self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1278, in _log
self.handle(record)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1288, in handle
self.callHandlers(record)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1328, in callHandlers
hdlr.handle(record)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 751, in handle
self.emit(record)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be there is an issues with the firewall. Please try to disabled plesk firewall and IPtables on your server for the testing purpose and check it again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out. I've tested disabling SELinux, IPtables, and there's no firewall installed on Plesk (that I can find). Still no dice. :(